# Probability of events using geometric series

Tags: probability

$P(\{n\}) = (1/2)^n$

$A = {n : 1 <= n <= 10}$

$B = {n : 1 <= n <= 20}$

$C = {n : 11 <= n <= 20}$

Find: $P(A), P(B), P(A \cup B), P(A \cap B), P(C)$ and $P(B')$

I need to use the geometric formula to solve them but I don't know how to set it up.

Comment: The event $A$ contains $10$ outcomes. Can you list them all? Can you make a list of the $10$ probabilities? Can you find the sum of the probabilities using a calculator? Have you ever seen a sum of the form you just calculated, maybe in a pre-calculus course in high school or middle school?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometric series come up fairly often in probability calculations. In this case, we want the sum of a finite geometric series. We give a "closed from" for the sum of such a series.

If $r\ne 1$, then
$$a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots+ar^{m}=\frac{a(1-r^{m+1})}{1-r}.$$
The formula can be verified by multiplying both sides by $1-r$. On the left side, there will be massive cancellation.

For the calculation of $\Pr(A)$, we need to choose $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and $r=\frac{1}{2}$. You should end up, after some simplification, with $1-\frac{1}{2^{10}}$, or equivalently $\frac{2^{10}-1}{2^{10}}$.

Now you can calculate $\Pr(B)$ and $\Pr(C)$. Since the probabilities of $A$, $B$, and $C$ have a nice relationship, you will really need to find the sum of one geometric series, not two.

The rest should be straightforward. It is best to look closely at the **meaning** of various things, such as $A\cap B$, before trying to resort to formulas.

Note that the numbers $1$ to $20$ are not the whole sample space, since the probability of $C$ is not $1$.

Comment: how do you know to choose a=1/2 and r=1/2.

Comment: The "general" series is $a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots$. Our series is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots$. If first terms are to match, we need $a=\frac{1}{2}$. If second terms are to match, we need $r=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: How would Pr(C) fit into the geometric formula since it doesn't start at 1?

Comment: There is an easy way and a harder way. Easy: the probability of $C$ is probability of $B$ minus probability of $A$. Harder: The prob. is $\frac{1}{2^{11}}+\dots +\frac{1}{2^{20}}$. This is a geometric series, $a=\frac{1}{2^{11}}$ and $r=\frac{1}{2}$.